# Assigning ngModel to property is undefined when coming from @Input

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I have a component with the following input property.

`@Input() addressAssociation: AccountAssociation;`

which has:
`address: Address;`

Inside Address there's a property I want to bind to, which is `stateCode`.

In my template I have this:

```
<div class="fcol-md-4 fcol-xs-12 form-group" *ngIf="!zipCodeValidating && addressAssociation.address">
  <label for="{{name}}State" class="uk-label">State / U.S Territory</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="addressAssociation.address.stateCode" 
    [disabled]="isListedZipCode"
    #addState="ngModel"
    required>
    <option [ngValue]="state.abbreviation" *ngFor="let state of states">{{state.fullName}} ({{state.abbreviation}})</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="text--error" *ngIf="addState.errors && addState.touched">
    <span *ngIf="addState.errors.required">State is required.</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the template loads, it always throws an error saying: `Cannot read property errors of undefined`.

Also, I tried to print the variable with `{{addState | json}}` but throws a circular reference error. And also, just trying to print addState, and it never changed even when going out from the disabled state and changing its value.

The thing is that apparently the variable `#addState` is not being populated with the `ngModel` any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Your template is likely loading before the variable is defined. One approach might be to use the safe navigation operator (?). addressAssociation?.address?.stateCode

Comment: @RobZuber the problem isn't in that piece of code, but in `errors`. To fix it: `addState?.errors` or even better `addState?.invalid` and to check errors: `addState?.hasError('required')`.

Comment: I've already tried that, but the value of addState never change and therefore, the save navigation operator doesn't fit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

You have a scoping issue. You are assigning the `#addState` inside an `*ngIf`. And then you are referencing `addState` OUTSIDE of that `*ngIf`. This does not work - the template variable will only be available inside the same scope that it was created. Try moving your error test div inside that `*ngIf`. Put it just under the `</select>`

**Old answer:**

You should be using the Safe Navigation Operator (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)

```
<div class="text--error" *ngIf="addState?.errors && addState?.touched">
    <span *ngIf="addState?.errors.required">State is required.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but the value of `addState` never change and therefore, the save navigation operator doesn't fit this.

Comment: Oh, I just twigged. You have a scoping issue.
You are assigning the `#addState` inside an `*ngIf`.
And then you are referencing addState OUTSIDE of that `*ngIf`.
This does not work - the template variable will only be available inside the same scope that it was created.
Try moving your error test div inside that `*ngIf`.
Put it just under the `</select>`

Comment: I see now, I didn't spot that *ngIf was causing the issue!

Comment: can you add your comment as an answer so I can vote it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is coming from this code

```
<div class="text--error" *ngIf="addState.errors && addState.touched">
    <span *ngIf="addState.errors.required">State is required.</span>
</div>
```

try adding addState to your ngIf

```
*ngIf="addState && addState.errors && addState.touched"
```

addState is not defined on component load so addState.errors produces that error